.NET MAUI redraw animation during switch between two TabBars
I have two TabBars in AppShell.xaml switching between them.
<TabBar>

    <Tab Title="Novinky">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Glyph="{StaticResource IconHome}"></FontImageSource>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:HomePage}" Route="HomePage" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Skupiny">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Glyph="{StaticResource IconGroups}"></FontImageSource>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="Skupiny" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:GroupListPage}" Route="GroupListPage" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Profil">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Glyph="{StaticResource IconUser}"></FontImageSource>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="Profil" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:ProfilePage}" />
    </Tab>
    
</TabBar>

<TabBar>

    <Tab Title="Oznámení">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Glyph="{StaticResource IconAnnouncement}"></FontImageSource>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="Oznámení" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:GroupPage}" Route="GroupPage" />
    </Tab>
    
    <Tab Title="Testy">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Glyph="{StaticResource IconTrials}"></FontImageSource>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="Testy" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:GroupTrialsPage}" Route="GroupTrialsPage" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Detail">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Glyph="{StaticResource IconInfo}"></FontImageSource>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="Detail" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:GroupDetailPage}" Route="GroupDetailPage" />
    </Tab>
    
</TabBar>

I navigate to GroupPage from GroupListPage like this
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(GroupPage)}", true,
    new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "Group", group }
    });

The navigation itself works fine but looks like the TabBar is being redrawn on the switch and have this kind of an animation, it looks bad especialy in dark mode. Also, it behaves like this only on Android. No such behaviour on Windows. I don't know about iOS.

I tried to change color in Styles.xaml for Shell properties but no luck. Any idea how to get rid of it or maybe just change the color of it?


The navigation itself works fine but looks like the TabBar is being redrawn on the switch and have this kind of an animation, it looks bad especialy in dark mode. Also, it behaves like this only on Android. No such behaviour on Windows. I don't know about iOS.

I tested the code you provided and reproduced the question. We tried to use Binding and INotifyPropertyChanged to dynamically change Visible of TabBar But it ended in failure. It still have that kind of the animation. You can report it on MAUI issue GitHub. Let our developers know and deal with it.
However, if you're willing to try using TabbedPage, it can eliminate that kind of the animation. And you can see the following code:
App.xaml.cs:
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static MyTabbedPage1 MyTabbedPage1;
    public static MyTabbedPage2 MyTabbedPage2;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = MyTabbedPage1 = new MyTabbedPage1();
        MyTabbedPage2 = new MyTabbedPage2();
    }
}

MyTabbedPage1:
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Views"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MyTabbedPage1"
             Title="MyTabbedPage1">

    <view:HomePage Title="Novinky" />
    <view:GroupListPage Title="Skupiny"/>
    <view:ProfilePage Title="Profil"/>
</TabbedPage>

MyTabbedPage2:
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Views"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MyTabbedPage2"
             Title="MyTabbedPage2">

    <view:GroupPage Title="Oznámení" />
    <view:GroupTrialsPage Title="Testy"/>
    <view:GroupDetailPage Title="Detail"/>
</TabbedPage>

GroupListPage:
public partial class GroupListPage : ContentPage
{
    public GroupListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = App.MyTabbedPage2;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new GroupPage());
    }
}

GroupPage:
public partial class GroupPage : ContentPage
{
    public GroupPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = App.MyTabbedPage1;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new GroupListPage());
    }
}

Here is the effect.
In addition, you can pass data by Messenger.

Using TabbedPage would mean to give up on the Shell navigation sadly. But thank you, glad to know you could reproduce it.

Well, it didn't solve the problem you know. This solution would mean to change the whole navigation logic.

Ok, I got that.
